# How to test whether the probability of a given colour of skittle is equal to that of another colour?

Tags: r, chi-squared-test

From a family pack skittles, some of the colours of different skittles are counted:

- 41 green,
- 48 purple
- 100 red
- 63 yellow.

Now I want to test if the probabilty of green is equal to the probability of purple; H0: P(green) = P(purple).

- How do I test this is R?
- Do I use a chi square test?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "probability" in this context?  For instance, if we were to draw one candy at random out of this pack, the probability of getting a green would equal $41/(41+48+100+63)$ and the probability of getting a purple would be similarly computed: it's obviously greater and the question is entirely trivial.

Comment: @whuber I suspect the question is the usual "Is this random chance or is there a systematic pro-Reddist conspiracy in the depths of the Skittle factory?"

Comment: @Epi Probably, but it usually isn't fruitful to answer a question based on what one suspects it might mean.  A great answer to a vague question can often confuse more than it helps.  That's why I have invited Wimpey to clarify this.

Comment: I have solved my problem, and for those interested in the answer, here is my R I/O:
x = c(41, 48)  
chisq.test(x, p=c(0.5, 0.5))$p.value  
[1]0:4580882. I hope this also clarifies my question, I am not sure how to formulate it in another way then I did before. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: If you have solved your own question, then you should enter the 'answer' below as a full answer (maybe expanding a little on your code and what it meant).  That way if someone else comes along with the same question, they'll see the question is answered, and then see your answer

Comment: For the record, Wimpey's solution in the comments above is incorrect and tests something completely different to what he/she originally asked.